# Harmonicity of the expectation of a stopped Brownian Motion

Tags: expectation, brownian-motion, harmonic-functions

Let $\mathbb{E}_x$ be the expectation associated with a probability measure such that $B_{t\geq0}$ is a Brownian motion started in x.
I want to show that for $D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ bounded, $y\in D, x\in D\setminus\{y\}$ and T the first exit time from D:
$$\mathbb{E}_x[log|B(T)-y|] \text{ is harmonic in x}$$

I was trying to prove it with the following theorem, but failed at the local boundedness.

> Let U be a domain, $B_t$ a Brownian motion started inside U and T the first hitting time of its boundary. Let f: $\partial U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable and such that the function $u:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $$u(x)=\mathbb{E}_x[f(B_T)], \text{ for every }x\in U,$$ is locally bounded. Then u is a harmonic function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is $D$ bounded?

Comment: Yes, D is bounded.

Comment: If $D$ is bounded (and open), then we can find $r,R>0$ such that $$0<r < |z-y| < R$$ for any $z \in \partial D$, so....

Comment: And how exactly do I get local boundedness with respect to x with that? Because that would only show local boundedness with respect to y, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $D$ is open and $y \in D$, we have

$$r := d(y,\partial D) := \inf\{z \in \partial D; |z-y| \}>0.$$

On the other hand, the boundedness of $D$ implies that we can choose $R>0$ such that $|z| \leq R$ for any $z \in \partial D$. Consequently,

$$\log r \leq \log|B(T)(\omega)-y| \leq \log (R+|y|)$$

holds for any $\omega \in \Omega$. Taking expectation yields

$$\log(r) \leq \underbrace{\mathbb{E}^x \log(|B(T)-y|)}_{=: u(x)} \leq \log(R+|y|)$$

for any $x \in D$. This shows that $u$ is not only locally bounded, but bounded. Therefore, the harmonicity follows by applying the theorem mentioned in the question.

Comment: Oh man, am I blind. But thanks, especially for this detailed answer!

Comment: @red You are welcome. :)